# Flutter - How to use icon and url launcher?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm learning flutter by my own and I would like to make an icon that works with `url_launcher` but I have no idea how to do it.
When I'm using icon, `onTap` doesn't work. How can I solve this issue?

```dart
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
  children: const [
    Icon(
      Icons.facebook_outlined,
      size: 80,
      color: Colors.black,
    )
  ],
),
```

Comment: You can use IconButton. Are you using GestureDetector?

Comment: Nope, dont know what is this actually :)

Comment: Replace Icon(...) with IconButton(onPressed: () { }, icon: Icons.facebook_outlined, iconSize: 80, color: Colors.black). There you have your onPressed callback in which you can write your URL launcher code.

Comment: Afridi Kayal thank you! It works <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Gesturedecture or IconButton

```
  Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: [
        GestureDetector(
         onTap:(){
          launchUrl();
        }
         child:Icon(
          Icons.facebook_outlined,
          size: 80,
          color: Colors.black,
        )
       )
      ],
    )
```

IconButton

```
IconButton(
icon: Icon(
      Icons.facebook_outlined,
      size: 80,
      color: Colors.black,
    ),
onPressed:(){
 launchUrl();
}

)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've needed this :)

Answer (score 2):

[`InkWell`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html) provides `onTap`, you can wrap `Icon` with it and I prefer splash effect. Also, you can use [`IconButton`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/IconButton-class.html) as @Afridi Kaya  commented.

```dart
Row(
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
children: [
  InkWell(
    onTap: () {
      print("tapped InkWell");
      /// todo: your launch
    },
    customBorder: const CircleBorder(),
    child: const Icon(
      Icons.facebook_outlined,
      size: 80,
      color: Colors.black,
    ),
  ),
  IconButton(
    onPressed: () {
      /// todo: your launch
      print("tapped IconButton");
    },
    iconSize: 80,
    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    icon: const Icon(
      Icons.facebook_outlined,
      color: Colors.black,
    ),
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IconButton`:

```
           Center(
            child: IconButton(
    
              icon: Icon(Icons.facebook_outlined),
    
              onPressed: () {
    
                setState(() {
    
                 _isBluetoothOn = !_isBluetoothOn;
    
                });
    
              },
    
            ),
    
          ),
```